# What does the -g global flag do when using pm install -g

Tags: installation, apk, command-line

I'm trying to get google play store to work on a proprietary custom ROM. I was given a hack to do this with my device. It's very hit or miss but I can get it working sometimes.

When I install Google Services Framework, Google Accounts Manager, and Services info app, the instructions say to use

```
pm install -g /package.apk
```

My understanding is that pm install is pretty much the same as just clicking the apk and installing it. But what does the `-g` flag accomplish? The reason I ask is because I'm running into many problems, and I'd like to have a better understanding of everything for troubleshooting purposes. Thanks.

Comment: `adb shell pm -h | grep -A20 'install ' | grep '\-g:'` returns: `-g: grant all runtime permissions`. I think it's pretty descriptive.

Comment: @IrfanLatif OOhhh wow so it's not _global_ it's actually short for _grant_. Thanks!

Comment: For any future viewers I wanted to add this link. Finally found a reference to all of the different options for pm install [here](http://adbcommand.com/adbshell/pm)

Comment: You can just run `pm` (or `adb shell pm` if running from a PC), and all options are displayed. It's a norm for commandline applications to show a brief help with `-h` or `--help` argument.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried -help and some variations of that. Didn't just try pm though for some reason.  Should have been more thorough. Minor changes coming from windows cmd/powershell to android/linux terminal may be throwing me off a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @IrfanLatif as it answers the question, maybe you make it into an answer of the question?

Comment: @silencedogood you can post an answer for future visitors' benefit .